# Using two tables to simulate a fixed header row, but header appears broken when scrolled left and right

Tags: html, css, html-table

I can't seem to figure out as to why my div/table column lines would appear broken if the body of the table was scrolled left and right. Their also appears to be some over run to the right of my html data table, how can I remedy these two problems. I've attached a pic of the problem:

[image]

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EPq69/

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#data_container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
}
#data_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    border-right:0px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
#data_headers, #data_body {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#data_headers {

}
#data_body {

}
#data_headers td, #data_body td {
    border-right: 1px solid green;
    width: 150px;
}
#data_headers td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="data_container">

        <table id="data_headers">
            <tr>
                <td>Header1</td>
                <td>Header2</td>
                <td>Header3</td>
                <td>Header4</td>
                <td>Header5</td>
                <td>Header6</td>
                <td>Header7</td>
                <td>Header8</td>
                <td>Header9</td>
                <td>Header10</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="data_wrapper">
        <table id="data_body">
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
                <td>Some content</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How come these 2 tables isn't combined into 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the overflow-x on the container. If you have the overflow-x on one of the tables then only that table will be scrolled and the other table will not be scrolling which is why you get the offset. If you put it on the container, both can be scrolled at the same time

```
#data_container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
     overflow-x: scroll;
}
#data_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    border-right:0px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPq69/1/

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any way to keep the header row fixed (stay in place at the top)?

Comment: When scrolling horizontally? If you make it fixed then you get the same issue as before when you scroll horizontally

Comment: No, just by scrolling vertically up and down?

Comment: If ONLY up and down then you can make the header table fixed and give the other table some margin top so they don't overlap. But this will not work if you scroll horizontally

Comment: user Huanhism, as per your answer horizontal scroll working but vertical scroll not working like sticky.